# Java SimpleDateFormat parse Timezone like America/Los_Angeles

Tags: java, parsing, timezone

I want to parse the following string in Java and convert it to a date:

```
DTSTART;TZID=America/Los_Angeles:20140423T120000
```

I tried this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("'DTSTART;TZID='Z':'yyyyMMdd'T'hhmmss");
Date start = sdf.parse("DTSTART;TZID=America/Los_Angeles:20140423T120000");
```

And this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("'DTSTART;TZID='z':'yyyyMMdd'T'hhmmss");
Date start = sdf.parse("DTSTART;TZID=America/Los_Angeles:20140423T120000");
```

But it still doesn't work. I think the problem is in America/Los_Angeles.
Can you help me please?

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this one using [TimeZone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html).

Note: You have to split your date string before doing this operation.

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'hhmmss");

    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");
    sdf.setTimeZone(tz);

    Date start = sdf.parse("20140423T120000");
```

---

In `SimpleDateFormat` pattern `Z` represent `RFC 822 4-digit time zone`

For more info have a look at [SimpleDateFormat#timezone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#rfc822timezone).

Comment: Probably this work, but it isn't what I need. Because I get a string like: DTSTART;TZID=America/Los_Angeles:20140423T120000.
I can use ur solution only if I first parse the string, than I use substring and so on. I'm looking for something faster.

Comment: @LorenzoTassone You are prematurely optimizing, a bad practice. Java is very fast. Splitting and parsing the String is an appropriate solution.

Comment: FYI, the terribly flawed date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) classes built into Java 8 and later.

Answer (score 8):

If you look for a solution how to parse the whole given string in one and only one step then [Java 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) offers this option (**the pattern symbol V** is not supported in `SimpleDateFormat`):

```
// V = timezone-id, HH instead of hh for 24-hour-clock, u for proleptic ISO-year
DateTimeFormatter dtf = 
  DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("'DTSTART;TZID='VV:uuuuMMdd'T'HHmmss");
ZonedDateTime zdt = 
  ZonedDateTime.parse("DTSTART;TZID=America/Los_Angeles:20140423T120000", dtf);
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant();

// if you really need the old class java.util.Date
Date jdkDate = Date.from(instant);
```

Comment: This answer should be the accepted one, because it uses Java 8's Time API.

Comment: why V twice, not once?

Comment: @Line Because the CLDR-standard had defined only two letters VV as valid symbol (and `java.time`-designers decided to follow it in most parts). Citation from the javadoc of class [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html): `ZoneId: This outputs the time-zone ID, such as 'Europe/Paris'. If the count of letters is two, then the time-zone ID is output. Any other count of letters throws IllegalArgumentException. `