# How can I parse this strange date-time format with Joda into a UTC DateTime?

Tags: java, date, datetime, jodatime

I am going around for a bit trying to parse this strange date format which I can't even find its name: `2016-05-03T10:40:47.559838+00:00`

With Java I would convert that into "2016-05-03T10:40:47.559838+0000" (notice the last `:` are gone) and use the following pattern "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ", but it probably does not guarantee me UTC.

What is the correct way of parsing this date into a Joda DateTime in UTC?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, `+00:00` or `+0000` _IS_ UTC...

Comment: For that single example yes

Comment: You cannot parse microseconds with Joda-Time (which has only millisecond precision). By the way, the "strange" date-time format you mention is valid ISO-8601, a technical format for exchange of temporal data.

Comment: @PedroD Please search Stack Overflow before posting. This issue has been covered many times already, such as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2201925/642706), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27064441/642706), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31090946/642706), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18483314/642706), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9077226/642706), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27270089/642706) and more.

Comment: The issue here is the milliseconds part :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the microseconds issue pointed out by Meno Hochschild, use the parser to parse as normal, then call upon [DateTime.withZone(DateTimeZone newZone)](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withZone(org.joda.time.DateTimeZone)) on the result of that to return a new instance of the DateTime converted to the desired time zone.